# How can I create a DKIM Record?

Tags: spf, dkim

I am not sure how to add a DKIM Record to my mails/server. Do I only have to generate it from here -> https://dkimcore.org/tools/keys.html and add it to my DNS?

Comment: After the keys are configured in DNS you will need to configure your mail server to actually generate the DKIM signatures and add them to your outgoing messages.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The idea of DKIM is as follows:

1.) You create a key pair, containing a public key and a secret key. What is encrypted with the secret key is (only) decryptable with the public key, and vice versa.

2.) You publish the public key in the DNS, along with a selector string that identifies that particular key pair.

3.) For any email you send, you calculate hashes of its headers and body, and sign the hashes using your secret key. You'll then add the results into the email in the form of a `DKIM-Signature:` header line. In practice, you want to set up your mail server to do this automatically for outgoing emails. The procedure for this depends on which mail server software you're using. This is probably the biggest task in the job of implementing DKIM.

4.) The recipients of your emails can now verify they're really from your server by verifying the hashes and the signature on them using the public key in the DNS.

5.) At your option, you can now also publish a [DMARC record](https://dmarc.org/) proclaiming that any messages with your domain as the sender and no corresponding DKIM header are fake and should be reported/quarantined/discarded.

The [on-line key generator](https://dkimcore.org/tools/keys.html) is recommended for testing purposes only. For real use, you should create the keys on your own computer.

[The DKIM Core specification](https://dkimcore.org/specification.html) indicates the keys can be generated quite simply by using OpenSSL command-line tools:

```
openssl genrsa -out example.com.priv 1024
openssl rsa -in example.com.priv -pubout >example.com.pub
```

Comment: Thanks, that was very helpful! Tho I do not have access to the server which sends the mail (it is provided by my hoster). I thought I have to install a cert on my executing server.